# Calculating flowpath length to stream within catchment using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, flow

ArcGIS 10.3 provides a hydrology tool "flow length" which calculates the length of flow paths within a basin to the *outlet* of the basin. I am trying to calculate flow path length and flow path gradient from a given pixel of interest to where it enters the *stream network*. Using TauDEM (which I do not have access to), they define this as the 'distance from a pixel of interest to the stream channel using the D8 flowpath direction'.

I have a 30m DEM, flow direction raster and river network. From these flow path values I need to calculate mean flowpath length and mean flowpath gradient for a catchment for use in a catchment classification study.

Using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Comment: Convert cells under stream into NO DATA value, recalculate flow length

Comment: How would I convert the cells under the stream layer to NO DATA? I can't just reclassify the flow direction layer because the stream network isn't consistently represented by one direction.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by converting the cells under the stream network to 'NO DATA' as per FelixIP's comment and recalculating the flow length.

I set the stream network cells to NO DATA using the Raster Calc equation:
SetNull(~(IsNull("Stream Raster")), "Original Flow Direction Raster")

Also of note, when calculating flow length, must set as DOWNSTREAM flow length.

Comment: @FelixIP
I have 15 catchments and I want to do the same as what Brun has done for each catchment. Is it possible to do that for all 15 catchments at the same time?

Comment: Yes it is. What stops you?